# Xcode -using two xcassets how would i override

Tags: ios, xcode, image, xcasset

Let me explain the architecture i'd like to build in xCode.  here is a photo of xcassets i have created in the project structure:

[image]

From the image you can see that i have created two xcassets folders.  The first one called images.xcassets hosts all images that are common to both my targets.Its membership is in both target1 and target2.  This xcassets sheet is filled with many images which i inherited from a fork.

The images-override.xcassets folder on the other hand, is where i'd like to put any images that ARE NOT common to both my targets. So the target membership for this directory should be only target2.

What im trying to accomplish:
Doing it this way, if i attempt to retrieve an image called myImage.png it should first check the images-override to see if any image is overriden, if its not found there it should then check images.xcassets for the image.

So my question is about what order the images will get searched for. I'd like the project to first check the images-overriden.xcassets sheet then check (if necessary) the images.xcassets folder.  Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot include multiple assets with the same name in Xcode. For your purpose, I'd recommend a naming convention:

`filename.png`
`filename-override.png`

For example. When loading your image, you first check if `filename-override.png` exists, if so load it. If not, load `filename.png`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, i want to do the image loading from InterfaceBuilder not through code. and i dont want to pollute my code with if conditions for an override.